# RobotFramework Configuration in Eclipse with Python?

Tags: python, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, robotframework

**Hi All**

I have python and robotframework installed on my Windows 7, I wanted to configure this into Eclipse IDE.

I was trying with External Tools to configure it by giving `Pybot.bat` file and working directory but I am able to understand the Arguments `${resources_loc}` section. Here what value we have to give??

can someone help me out with this or provide alternative to configure it?

Comment: @Michael Tingey could you please help I have gone through your answer but unfortunately unable to comment there due to less reputations?

Comment: @Bryan Oakley your comments would be helpful?

Comment: Why do you think  my comments would be helpful? I don't use windows and I don't use Eclipse.

Comment: that's fine I am just starting with these combinations and I have gone through your Edit of related question, assumption is you have knowledge about it.

Answer (score 0):

When Eclipse is your main IDE and prefer to use it for developing Robot Framework scripts, then there is only one plugin you need to be aware of [Nokia RED](https://github.com/nokia/red). It can be downloaded from the Eclipse market place and adds a new perspective for the dedicated robot functionality.

In the [RED Robot Editor User Guide](http://nokia.github.io/RED/help/) there is a specific section on running a RED Robot project providing you with all the details. However, I recommend you start with the "[Hello World](http://nokia.github.io/RED/help/first_steps/create_run.html)" section.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you try PyCharm Community edition for Robot Framework with Python. It has all the necessary configuration for you to make. [Here is the link for PyCharm CE](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm-edu/download/#section=windows). 
  It has all the required plugging in its settings-> Interpreter options. You can download all the robot framework plugins and libraries that is required for you to write and execute the code.

Comment: Thank you @CodeFlash that would be helpful